# find distinct nested data with count and limit of highest order in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find only 5 records of the highest count with unique data, I am using below:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{$unwind: '$restaurantcompetitors'},
{$unwind: '$restaurantcompetitors.competitorName'},
{$group: {_id: '$restaurantcompetitors.competitorName', count:{$sum:1}}}
```

)

I am getting result like:

```
{ "_id" : "Platterz.co", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "ChowNow", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "cater2.me", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "App-App.co", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "airportsherpa.io", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Eat24", "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "Chowbus", "count" : 5 }
```

But I want:

```
{ "_id" : "Chowbus", "count" : 5 }
{ "_id" : "Eat24", "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "ChowNow", "count" : 3 }
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: use `$sort` with `count` and  then put `$limit`

Comment: thanks @Anthony Winzlet for your attention. can you pleas give me example

Answer (score 1):

Use `$sort` with count and then use `$limit`

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  { '$unwind': '$restaurantcompetitors' },
  { '$unwind': '$restaurantcompetitors.competitorName' },
  { '$group': {
    '_id': '$restaurantcompetitors.competitorName',
    'count': { '$sum': 1    }
  }},
  { '$sort': { 'count': -1 }},
  { '$limit': 3 },
)
```